# Значение понятия "дискретность"

Tags: значение-слов

"Дискретность" - это всякая разрывность или только разрывность во времени? Возможно ли выражение "дискретные (необъединенные) знания"?

Comment: _Отрывочные_ знания.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы по отношению к знаниям сказала "фрагментарные". Вы, однако, хотите втянуть нас в научную философскую дискуссию:

https://www.pravdologia.ru/forum/forum18/topic3402/
http://evreimir.com/126638/3/

> Знание есть информация, описывающая свойства объектов. То есть знание
>   состоит из структурированного множества описаний отдельных свойств
>   объектов. Поэтому знание – дискретно и структурно.

Мне кажется, здесь слово "знание" подменено понятием "информация".

Непрерывная и дискретная информация - это понятно:

> Информация о различных природных явлениях и технологических процессах
>   воспринимается человеком (при помощи органов чувств и/или различной
>   измерительной аппаратуры) в виде каких-либо полей. С математической
>   точки зрения такие поля представляют собой функции   , где t – время,
>   x – точка, в которой измеряется поле, y – величина поля в этой точке.
>   При измерениях поля в фиксированной точке x=a функция   вырождается в
>   функцию времени   , которую можно изобразить в виде графика. В
>   большинстве случаев все скалярные величины, входящие в соотношение
>   (т.е. t, y и координаты точки x), могут принимать непрерывный ряд
>   значений, измеряемых вещественными числами. Под непрерывностью здесь
>   понимается то, что рассматриваемые величины могут изменяться сколь
>   угодно мелкими шагами. Поэтому представленную таким образом информацию
>   называют непрерывной информацией. Иногда для этой цели используется
>   термин аналоговая информация.
>   https://lektsii.org/2-84783.html

Дискре́тность  — свойство, противопоставляемое непрерывности , прерывность. Дискретность — всеобщее свойство материи, под дискретностью понимают:

1. Нечто, изменяющееся между несколькими различными стабильными состояниями, например механические часы, которые передвигают минутную стрелку дискретно на 1/60 часть окружности
2. Нечто, состоящее из отдельных частей, прерывистость, дробность. Например, дискретный спектр , дискретные структуры, дискретные сообщения.

Впрочем, знания во втором значении и есть совокупность сведений, т.е. информация. Вероятно, возможно сказать и "дискретные знания", т.е. дробные. Но я бы по отношению к знаниям не говорила, что они **прерывные** или **непрерывные**.

Смотря что Вы хотите сказать, трудно ответить на Ваш вопрос, не видя всей фразы, в корректности которой сомневаетесь.